# Probabilistic Proof of Chebyshev Inequality - Step 3

Tags: probability, probability-theory, inequality, integral-inequality

[Here](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Chebyshev%27s_inequality#Probabilistic_proof) you can find the probabilistic proof of the Chebyshev Inequality. I don't understand Step 3 which uses the following inequality:

$$
\mathbb{E}\left[\mathbf{I}_{\{ X^2 >1\}} \right] \leq \mathbb{E}\left[X^2\right]
$$

Can you explain why this is true?

Answer (score 4, accepted):

Note that 
$$X^2 = X^2 I_{\{X^2 > 1\}} + X^2 I_{\{X^2 \leq 1\}} \geq X^2 I_{\{X^2 > 1\}} \geq I_{\{X^2 > 1\}}.$$
Then take expectations on both sides.

Comment: Thank you. This only works if the bound is 1, right? Imo this is not so easy to see and a small comment in the wikipedia article would help.

Comment: @stollenm Yes, I use that the lower bound is $1$ in passing to the final inequality.

Answer (score 2):

You need to recall that
\begin{equation}
\mathbb{E}\left[\mathbf{I}_{A} \right] = P(X\in A) = \int_A dP 
\end{equation}

Therefore,
\begin{equation}
\mathbb{E}\left[\mathbf{I}_{\{X^2>1\}} \right] = \int_{\{X^2>1\}} dP\leq \int_{\{X^2>1\}} X^2dP  \leq \int_{\{X^2>1\}\cap\{X^2<1\}} X^2dP =\int_\mathbb{R} X^2 dP 
\end{equation}
because $X^2$ is greater than 1.